# need help getting rid of a virus

Tags: windows, virus, malware, malwarebytes

I'm getting this virus about 8-18 happen at once. My Avast! is blocking it but it triggers when ever I shut down my computer, and turn it on again. I have done a virus scan with Avast! and MalwareBytes but nothing is found.

I don't know how to get rid of it.

P.S. This is what my avast says:

```
URL:http://simplesitescan.net/4343/BocaProc_142667268793723.dll Infection: URL:Mal Process: C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe
```

Comment: [How to remove SvcHost.exe virus (Malware Removal Guide)](http://malwaretips.com/blogs/svchost-exe-virus-removal/)

Answer (score 0):

Next, you might consider using **ComboFix**. But be careful, if it is not used properly, it can damage your system.

Comment: Combofix is a bit of a black box. What does it do? When's it appropriate to use it?

Comment: From my experience - it was able to remove a few Virus/Malware infections that were impossible to get rid of using other means (Avast, Norton, NOD32). What it does? Well, it leaves a log after a successful run, so you can look it up. How it does it? Beats me.